# DataTable: Misaligned header and content in p:dataTable with vertical scrolling

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Environment :

```
JsfContainer 2.3
Primefaces 6.2
Liberty 18.0.0.4
```

DataTable with scrollable="true" having column width issue. its cutting the data of the column if the content is greater than column header width. if I am making scrollable="false" it's showing all the contents with proper width but it's adding page scrollbar.

[image]

But It's working fine in environment

```
JsfContainer 2.2 
Primefaces 6.2
```

Comment: Tried latest pf snapshot?

Comment: You mean Primefaces 6.3-SNAPSHOT?

Comment: 7.0... But there is a 7.0RC3 in maven iirc already... (or RC2)

Comment: Its working fine in 7.0RC2 and 7.0RC3. Even its working fine in Primefaces-6.1 and some lower versions. But what is the reason why its not properly working in 6.2.?

Comment: Compare sourcode of the two versions. And check the issuelist and the commits. The source **IS** open. And maybe check the elite release, it mignt have been an accidental regression that was fixed in there.